# Scrolling navbar with gradient

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a navigation bar with a fading gradient for the mobile version of a page. For a demonstration of what I'm describing, take a look at the mobile version of the Google search result page. The when you scroll the horizontal navbar (with links to news, shopping, images, etc. subpages), the far left and right of the text fades out.

[image: google search result 1]

[image: google search result 2]

[image: google search result 3]

As you can see, each of the navbars show fading gradients, at the same places relative to the viewport and at different places relative to the navigation links. On the first, the gradients are on 'alles' and 'shopping', on the second, the gradients are on 'alles' and the 'm' in maps, and on the third the gradient is on 'news' and no text is far enough to the right to have a gradient.

The challenge here is that the text needs to be scrollable, and the gradient needs to stay in the same place in the viewport. The position of the gradient relative to the text needs to change as the text scrolls.

All of the solutions I've found for gradient text with CSS involve using a `-webkit-linear-gradient` background with `-webkit-background-clip: text;`, and `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;`. This basically creates a gradient background which contours the text, and then makes the text invisible so the background can be seen. The background doesn't scroll.

Are there any solutions to this problem using CSS?

Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment

Comment: When I use `background-attachment: local;`, the gradient is applied to the whole navigation text. Meaning, the center text is the most opaque and the further to the left or right one scrolls, the more the it fades. This isn't the desired behavior. The other background-attachment settings have no effect.

Comment: This isn’t a gradient applied to the text in the first place in this example, these are simply small elements positioned above this row of links, that have a semi-transparent gradient set as background … And since those elements _stay_ in their position, there is no need to modify/adapt this gradient “position” at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create an overflowing div on top of your bar with `pointer-event: none;`. This div would contain a gradient background from white to transparent to white again. It can be done using css or an image.

```css
.bar {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.gradient {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
  <div class="gradient">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.nav-outter {
    position: relative;
}

.nav-outter::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 80px;
    height: 100%;
    content: '';
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #fff, transparent);
    pointer-events: none;
}

.nav-outter::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 80px;
    height: 100%;
    content: '';
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #fff, transparent);
    pointer-events: none;
}

.nav {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    background-color: #ddd9d9;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.336);
    overflow: auto;
}

.nav-link {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}

.nav-link:hover {
    border-bottom-color: dodgerblue;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-outter">
 <div class="nav">
  <div class="nav-link">Home</div>
  <div class="nav-link">Images</div>
  <div class="nav-link">News</div>
  <div class="nav-link">Videos</div>
  <div class="nav-link">Home</div>
  <div class="nav-link">Images</div>
  <div class="nav-link">News</div>
  <div class="nav-link">Videos</div>
  <div class="nav-link">Home</div>
  <div class="nav-link">Images</div>
  <div class="nav-link">News</div>
  <div class="nav-link">Videos</div>
  <div class="nav-link">Home</div>
  <div class="nav-link">Images</div>
  <div class="nav-link">News</div>
  <div class="nav-link">Videos</div>
 </div>
</div>
```